Will the efficiency of PMSM motor increase if it is rewound for high voltage keeping everything else the same?
The background is:
I have to redesign a 10.8 volt DC-battery supply, PMSM 3-phase motor to work with 24VDC. I can only rewind the current motor and adjust it to 24VDC.
The motor is rated for 550 watts of output power.

Why does the efficiency not increase?
In general is it possible to have 96% efficiency for 550 watt 3 phase PMSM motors while keeping the M270-50A lamination material?


The way you ask makes me think assignment. why is the efficiency not increasing? Is that so? Same resistance between battry&windings, I'd expect reduced resistive losses - and increased switching losses. M270-50A is not a choice for low weight or losses.

(Chances are the machine is used in star configuration with 10.8 V - any chance to switch to delta? If yes, I wouldn't rewind.)

@greybeard:  Rewinding to high voltage from low voltage increases the resistance of winding proportionally for the same copper area .
I was looking online for motors with 550Watt rating which have efficiency more the 95%. But i couldnot find any. Do you have any suggestions?

(I think BLDC as EM machine + inverter/motor controller/ESC. (I'm aware you use PMSM.) The switching losses are caused in the electronics - same as the reduced resistive losses at these voltage levels. Resistive lossed would not change in the windings given same winding material&weight)

Rewinding a motor by hand is likely to reduce efficiency, as you rarely achieve the same amount of copper as the original machine winding managed. Less copper fraction means higher resistance => higher I2R losses.
As for changing the voltage/current ratio, unless you go to extreme ratios, where the insulation on fine wire starts taking significant area, or the voltage drop on high current lead-in wires or ESC devices becomes significant, the efficiency would be expected to stay pretty much the same.
